# getch not working without initscr

Tags: ncurses, getch

I gone through the [Documentation](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/keys.html) of NCURSES. I am not getting that if I use getch without initscr then why this program is not working. Is there any other approach to get arrow keys input without clearing screen (that initscr do).

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    int ch;
    //initscr();
    //raw();
    //keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    //noecho();

    while(1)
    {
        ch = getch();
        switch(ch)
        {
            case KEY_UP: 
                printw("\nUp Arrow");
                break;
            case KEY_DOWN: 
                printw("\nDown Arrow");
                break;
            case KEY_LEFT: 
                printw("\nLeft Arrow");
                break;
            case KEY_RIGHT: 
                printw("\nRight Arrow");
                break;
        }

        if(ch == KEY_UP)
            break;
    }
    //endwin();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you may use change the terminal attribute through `tcsetattr` in `termios`. If you cycle between the `canonical mode` (requires new line for the process to begin) and `non-canonocal mode` (Keypress is more than enough).

The following program works as follows - THe process waits for user input. If up arrow key is pressed, it prints 'Arrow key pressed' and exits. If something else is pressed, it waits for the user to press `Enter` and then prints the user inpu. Exits after the inut is printed.

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  struct termios oldt, newt;
  char ch, command[20];
  int oldf;

  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
  newt = oldt;
  newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
  oldf = fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL, 0);
  fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, oldf | O_NONBLOCK);

  while(1)
  {
    ch = getchar();
    if (ch == '\033')
    { printf("Arrow key\n"); ch=-1; break;}
    else if(ch == -1) // by default the function returns -1, as it is non blocking
    {
      continue;
    }
    else
    {
      break;
    }

  }
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
  fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, oldf);
  if(ch != EOF)
  {
    ungetc(ch,stdin);ith
    putchar(ch);
    scanf("%s",command);
    printf("\n%s\n",command);

    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: My answer is relevant to ". Is there any other approach to get arrow keys input without clearing screen (that initscr do)." and not to the question title

Comment: I provided an alternative solution to your question. I am still not sure this is the answer you really wanted.

Answer (score 2):

`getch` is the same as `wgetch(stdscr)`.  It assumes that the screen has been initialized. ncurses (any curses implementation) has to do a couple of things to make [`wgetch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters) usable:

- read the terminal description
- initialize the terminal I/O modes
- allocate a screen to draw on.

The last is because `wgetch` does a [`wrefresh`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_refresh.3x.html) on the window for which it was called, before doing a read.

You could use [newterm](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-newterm) with [`filter`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-filter_nofilter) to avoid clearing the screen, and doing line-oriented input.  The `filter` program in [ncurses-examples](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-examples.html) demonstrates how to do this.

Comment: with use of filter and newterm, it is working, but not showing  any printw statements. It shows ^[[A for 'up arrow key'  instead of printw("\nUp Arrow"); statement output.

Comment: You have to call `keypad(stdscr,TRUE);` to fix that.  Also, using `filter`, it only displays on the current line -- and a `printw` containing a newline will clear the (one-line) window.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution without ncurses

You can use [simple-getch](https://github.com/mouuff/simple-getch) like this:

```
t_key keys[] = {
  {"[A", K_UP},
  {"[B", K_DOWN},
  {"[D", K_LEFT},
  {"[C", K_RIGHT},
  {NULL, K_UNK},
};

int key;

ch_init();
while ((key = ch_get(keys)) != K_BACK)
  {
    printf("%d\n", key);
  }
ch_end();
```

`keys` array is a list of escape sequences which will be used, (when you type an arrow key in a terminal, it will write an escape key followed by multiples characters to define the key.)

This sequences may/will change between terminals, you should use [termcap](https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_mono/termcap.html) to properly set this sequences.